# Linux Expect waiting before exiting

Tags: linux, expect

> ```
> #!/usr/bin/expect
> # Test expect script to telnet.
>
> spawn telnet 192.168.1.1
> expect "Username: "
> send "adminpldt\r"
> expect "Password: "
> send "password\r"
> expect "$"
> send "show lan\r"
> send "show\r"
> expect eof
> close
> # end of expect script.
> ```

Here is the problem, when I run this code, it shows the correct output. But it doesn't exit afterwards, it's like waiting for an input. Like a timeout. But if I remove the line
"EXPECT EOF". it terminates immediately. Can someone help me? I just started inLinux scripting and I've searched every topic on stackoverflow

EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED

```
>     >     #!/usr/bin/expect
>     >     # Test expect script to telnet.
>     >     
>     >     spawn telnet 192.168.1.1
>     >     expect "Username: "
>     >     send "adminpldt\r"
>     >     expect "Password: "
>     >     send "password\r"
>     >     expect "$"
>     >     send "sh\r"
>     >     send "config\r"
>     >     send "macc interface lan1 [lindex $argv 0]\r"
>     >     send "macc interface lan2 [lindex $argv 0]\r"
>     >     send "macc interface lan3 [lindex $argv 0]\r"
>     >     send "macc interface lan4 [lindex $argv 0]\r"
>     >     send "macc interface wlan [lindex $argv 0]\r"
>     >     send "exit\r"
>     >     send "exit\r"
>     >     expect eof
>     >     # end of expect script.
```

I got it. eof is when it it goes back to bash. I just realized that when I fully mastered my router config.

Comment: By terminating immediately I mean it shows this...
spawn telnet 192.168.1.1
Trying 192.168.1.1...
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
Escape character is '^]'.

User Access Verification

Username: adminpldt

Password:

Then it goes back to the bash.

Comment: Maybe the `interact` command is what you are looking for?

Comment: I tried interact in place of expect eof and close. It still doesn't close immediately but it shows the right stuff

Comment: Sorry about that, I initially misunderstood what you were trying to achieve. How about `expect "$"` after both `send "show lan\r"` and `send "show\r"`, and remove `expect eof`? You may run into trouble when command output contains `$` characters, though. Try to refine your `expect` pattern, e.g. by adding the trailing space (if any): `expect "$ "`

Comment: Ruud is correct: you should (almost) always expect some result before you send something new. After the "show" command, do you need to `send "exit\r"` before the telnet session can end?

Comment: @glennjackman . Ruud. The telnet session will end, But it will bring me back to the username password screen. I was looking for a way to exit the expect script immediately after achieving my intentions

Comment: When you enter a telnet session manually, what do you have to do to exit it?

Comment: I have to send "exit\r" depends on where I', at with the router. The issue on that tho is that it doesn't really exit. It goes back to login screen. I was thinking terminating the expect script itself.

Comment: It's good practice to logout from the server before killing the client; I'd say it is a good thing you return to the username prompt. So how about a final `expect "Username: "` before `close`?

Comment: I was thinking about that when I finally figured out how to exit it immediately, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# Test expect script to telnet.

spawn telnet 192.168.1.1
expect "Username: "
send "adminpldt\r"
expect "Password: "
send "password\r"
expect "$"
send "sh\r"
send "config\r"
send "macc interface lan1 [lindex $argv 0]\r"
send "macc interface lan2 [lindex $argv 0]\r"
send "macc interface lan3 [lindex $argv 0]\r"
send "macc interface lan4 [lindex $argv 0]\r"
send "macc interface wlan [lindex $argv 0]\r"
send "exit\r"
send "exit\r"
expect eof
# end of expect script.
```

I got it. eof is when it it goes back to bash. I just realized that when I fully mastered my router config.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `'expect eof'`, use `'expect " "'`.

There is no eof in a telnet session. Even without the close command, it will exit immediately. I'm still not sure about the expect "$" though. it should've worked. It's just sad it's not an ">" but an "$"

Comment: expect's eof is when the spawned process closes its terminal connection (likely because it closes). It is unrelated to an eof on the telnet connection, which indeed does not happen.